# strip out xml tags inside placeholders

Tags: xml, replace, sed, placeholder, strip

I would like to use sed (or other tool) to strip out xml tags but only in specific locations, marked with '{{' '}}' placeholders. 
Example:

```
<ok><ok2>{{TextShouldStay<not_ok>this_should_be_out</not_ok>
<sthelse/>ThisShouldBeAgain}}</ok2></ok>
```

Expected result:

```
<ok><ok2>{{TextShouldStayThisShouldBeAgain}}</ok2></ok>
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: does the {{}}  block contains newline chars? did you wanna Perl answer?

Comment: mandatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552

Comment: @AvinashRaj: no newlines, Perl answer would be fine as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Command:**

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file.xml | sed -r 's/(.*\{\{)([A-Za-z0-9]*)(<.*\/>)(.*)/\1\2\4\n/g'
```

**Output:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat file.xml
<ok><ok2>{{TextShouldStay<not_ok>this_should_be_out</not_ok>
<sthelse/>ThisShouldBeAgain}}</ok2></ok>
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ tr '\n' ' ' < file.xml | sed -r 's/(.*\{\{)([A-Za-z0-9]*)(<.*\/>)(.*)/\1\2\4\n/g'
<ok><ok2>{{TextShouldStayThisShouldBeAgain}}</ok2></ok>
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$


Here we remove the newlines first using 'tr' and then group the patterns using '(' and ')'. 
First group - from beginning of line to '{{' inclusive
Second group - after '{{', whatever alphabets/numbers
Third group - characters between the next '<' and last '/>'
Fourth group - remaining characters.

Once grouped, we remove the 3rd pattern group, also add newline.
```